# How do I alter/change the names of multiple columns with one command using SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to change all my column names from their default name to a custom one all at once. any tips?

Comment: As far as I know, you have to rename them one at a time in SQLite.

Comment: Column names don't have "defaults".  They have the names assigned when the table is created.